# Return singleton value in MVVM for binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use a value from a singleton as my binding. I want to do something like this?

```
public class MySingleton : INotifyPropertyChanged    
{
   //...inotifypropertychanged and singleton implementation

   private bool _isChecked;
   public bool IsChecked
   {
       get 
       { 
           return _isChecked; 
       }
       set
       {
          _isChecked= value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
       }
    }

    //...other implementation
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //...inotifypropertychanged and other implementation

  public bool IsAllChecked { get { return MySingleton.GetInstance().IsChecked; } }
}
```

Some Xaml:

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked = "{Binding IsAllChecked}"/>
```

I have tried this and the bindings don't seem to update. I have tried this with `ObservableCollection` and it works great but other types aren't. I figure that it is something special with `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: if `MyViewModel` doesn't raise PropertyChanged for IsAllChecked, nothing will happen (don't blame ObservableCollection which is totally different case - INotifyCollectionChanged). why not declare `Instance` property instead of `GetInstance()` method and bind to `MySingleton.Instance` directly?

Comment: I didn't realize you could access a singleton from XAML. So I could just `<ToggleButton IsChecked = "{Binding MySingleton.Instance.IsChecked}"/>`

Comment: no quite. `"{Binding Path=IsChecked, Source={x:Static myNameSpace:MySingleton.Instance}}"`

Comment: That works like a charm. Thanks! If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyViewModel` doesn't raise `PropertyChanged` for `IsAllChecked` property, update in UI will not happen (`ObservableCollection` is totally different case - `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

why not declare `Instance` property instead of `GetInstance()` method and bind to `MySingleton.Instance` directly?

```
"{Binding Path=IsChecked, Source={x:Static myNameSpace:MySingleton.Instance}}"
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why is ObservableCollection totally different?

Comment: @jharr100,ObservableCollection implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and reports about *items* changing ([NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), "Notifies listeners of dynamic changes, such as when an item is added and removed or the whole list is cleared.")