# WPF Converter Static Text

Tags: wpf, data-binding, static, converters

I'm trying to implement my own Translator using Converters. In the converter I call a static class containing translations. This translations are loaded when application starts.

The main advantage using this converters for me are three:

1. I translate texts in runtime, based on XML language files.
2. When executing application I register text without translation in other XML file, so I can later add the translation.
3. Translations are applied also to data when desired.

All works fine when the text to translate comes from a binded property, per example:

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding NameToShow, Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}}"></TextBox>
```

The problem is translating static text like labels, button content... The idea is making something like this:

```
<Button Content={Binding "MyText",Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}} Command="{Binding InitializeAdapterCommand}"></Button>
```

Obviously, I want neither to declare static strings in resources or to use bindable properties.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `MarkupExtension` instead of relying on Bindings:

```
public class StaticTranslation : MarkupExtension
{
    public StaticTranslation()
    {
    }

    public StaticTranslation(string textToTranslate)
    {
        TextToTranslate = textToTranslate;
    }

    public string TextToTranslate { get; set; }

    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

    public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Converter != null)
        {
            return Converter.Convert(TextToTranslate, typeof(string), ConverterParameter, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        }
        return TextToTranslate;
    }
}
```

And use it with `lib` being the `xmlns:lib=[namespace containing StaticTranslation]`

```
<TextBlock Text="{lib:StaticTranslation 'ABC',Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}}"/>
```

Ofcourse the converter usage in `StaticTranslation` is just an example. You may want to test / improve the code for production usage.

Side note:

If you get an error when nesting `Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}`, move your markup extension to a separate class library project. See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785549/5265292

Comment: It works perfect. I have already defined Converter in a class library project for reusing purpose, so it has worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Binding.Source` property to pass a const value to a converter:

```
Text="{Binding Source='My Text', Converter={StaticResource TranslationConverter}}"
```

Comment: Oh dear, I was thinking of providing some sort of `x:Static` to the binding source before opting to write my answer, but I completely failed to try the most simple source assignment, was already thinking to complicated. +1

Comment: @grek40, `"{Binding Source={x:Static smth}}"` is also working :)
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175467/return-singleton-value-in-mvvm-for-binding). same with `"{Binding Source={StaticResource resourseKey}}"`

Comment: Yes I know... but I somehow tried to combine such an extension with directly writing the text and not to use it to get resources or static properties, because the question wasn't about redirecting to a resource or property :)